# Social authentication in JAX-RS

Tags: java, angularjs, spring, jakarta-ee, spring-social

I'm developing a Java application using JPA, EJB, CDI, JAX-RS and AngularJS, running on a WildFly.

Currently I use [basic authentication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication), but I would like to improve it with other authentication options, such as Facebook, Twitter or Google+.

[Spring Social](http://projects.spring.io/spring-social/) provides a nice set of features to connect with social networks, but I'm not using Spring on my application.

My questions are:

- Does Spring Social play well with EJB?
- Is there any example?
- Is there an alternative to Spring Social in order to connect with social networks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm running a web application using exactly the same stack and I'm successfully using Spring Social for Facebook authentication.
To answer your questions:

- Spring Social is a class library, sure you can use it with EJBs, in
  my project I've actually created an abstract interface between a
  facade EJB and various Spring Social providers;
- you can find code
  examples on the [Spring Social web page](http://projects.spring.io/spring-social-facebook/), look at Spring Sample
  Projects;
- every social gives you libraries and tools to connect with
  them, whereas the Spring Social library gives you a uniform interface, making your code more simple and maintainable.